# How to resume the spring state machine from the last state it was in just before the server went down?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-statemachine

Assuming I want to model an order on an e-commerce website using the SSM with states -(S1,S2,S3). A particular order was at S2 when the server got restarted. I want the order to be able to pick up from S2 and resume the next time.
One way I can think of doing this is by persisting the SSM ID and the state "S2" in database just after the order transitions from S1 to S2.
Alongwith this we can have an admin panel where anyone can enter the SSM ID and submit. This SSM ID can be used to retrieve the state of the Order from the database. But then, I'll have to write an if-else block that emits an appropriate event which would look something like:

```
if (stateFromDatabase.equals("S1") {
    stateMachine.sendEvent("E1");
} else if (stateFromDatabase.equals("S2")) {
    stateMachine.sendEvent("E2");
} else if (stateFromDatabase.equals("S3")) {
    stateMachine.sendEvent("E3");
}
```

This doesn't seem to be a decent thing to do, I want to know if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: let me know if you figured that out

Answer (score 0):

The use case you are describing is very similar to the [Persist Recipe](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/#statemachine-examples-persist). If you want to deal with servers being restarted, you need a persistence storage. In your case I'd have an instance of State Machine persisted in the DB for each order, you can give the machine any ID (including the order ID), or map in the order a machine UUID.

The machine current state is also persisted and should reflect the order status in case you don't have it in the order itself